# Is an aria-label needed for basic (all) link tags?

Tags: html, wai-aria, lighthouse

Trying to figure out why a Lighthouse audit flagged a bunch of my links as failing the `elements have discernible names`

```
<h3>
  <a href="https://..." class="custom classes here">My New Post Title</a>
</h3>
```

My question is do all links need `aria-labels` because I thought if it's just a normal link the text inside the link is what is required?

Or is there something else going on with the structure of my markup? Another flagged element is this one:

```
<a class="custom classes" href="https://...">
  <div class="custom classes" style="background-image: url('https://...');"></div>
  <div class="article-thumbnails-small__title">Post Title</div>
</a>
```

For that one I understand that the `a` has no text so the `aria-label` should go on the div with the actual post title, correct?

**SOLVED**
I was looking at the wrong element... Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your examples are fine and should not be flagged.  Something else must be going on.  Is the code you posted exactly what was being tested?

ARIA attributes should be used sparingly and are only meant to be used when native markup isn't sufficient.  For links, as you said, if there's any text between the `<a>...</a>`, then that's "discernible text".

If the link doesn't have any direct text but if a child element does, then you're also ok, such as your second example.  The `<a>` doesn't have text but the second `<div>` has "Post Title".  All the child elements of the `<a>` are considered when looking for the "discernible text".  When I <kbd>tab</kbd> to that link, I'll hear "Post Title, link" from a screen reader.

However, CSS can affect this.  If your `class="article-thumbnails-small__title"` on the second `<div>` has a `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, then that text will **not** be discernible because it's hidden.

If the class has `width/height:0px`, then it **might** not be discernible either.  Sometimes 0 sized elements are considered hidden.

If your link does not have text but has a nested `<img>`, as long as the image has `alt` text, then you're ok.

**Good:**

```
<a href="foo.html">
  <img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo">
</a>
```

**No Discernible Text:**

```
<a href="foo.html">
  <img src="foo.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Really informative answer, thank you. Not sure if this is an issue with Lighthouse then because I can't tell what would make it fail. I have about 12 instances of this structure (anchor inside h3 inside a display:grid) and they are all for sure visible as they are just black text on white a background...

Comment: I would highly doubt it's a Lighthouse issue.  Lighthouse uses aXe (by Deque) for it's accessibility rules, and aXe's primary goal is "no false positives".  They'd rather have an issue not detected than to report an issue falsely.  You can install the aXe extension for Firefox or Chrome.  If you run aXe on your page, you should get the same "discernible text" error as Lighthouse.  Can you bring up the code inspector on the offending page and copy/paste the `display:grid` parent (and subsequent h3 and anchor children) to their own file and run aXe/Lighthouse on it?  Perhaps post that code too.

Comment: So I finally realized I was looking at the wrong element... I had an additional link sibling to that h3 that had an image inside and that was causing the issue. I'll upvote though because you did answer various other questions I had with your response!

Comment: Thanks for upvoting but the answer should be marked as correct because I addressed the image problem at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `aria-label` attribute on links (`a` elements with a `href` attribute) should only be used when, for whatever reason, it is not possible or not desirable to use perceivable link text. (This includes the `alt` attribute in image links.) If you have normal link text, you *should not* use the `aria-label` attribute because that attribute would override the link text. See [step F](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2F) of the [text alternative computation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd_te) in the document Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1: the `a` element has an inherent role that allows the computation of its name from its content (i.e. the link text and/or the `alt` attribute on an `img` in the link). However, this step is only followed if there is *no `aria-label` attribute* on the link element (see [step C](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2C).

See also [Principle 2: ARIA Can Both Cloak and Enhance, Creating Both Power and Danger](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#no_aria_better_bad_aria) in the WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1, which points out that ARIA sometimes overrides the original semantics or content, citing `aria-label` as an example.

So if Lighthouse flags links with perceivable link text and no `aria-label` attribute, there must be something else going on, such as CSS that hides elements.

Comment: Do you know if Lighthouse or Axe will flag an override that is bad practice? if I had an aria label on a parent with a child that had text for example?

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach Lighthouse does not flag every `aria-label` on an element (e.g. `div`) that has child elements with text content. (`a` elements are focusable, which may make a difference.)